# Role of a Business Systems analyst in Data Warehouse Application

Tags: database, system, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, analysis

Can someone explain me in detail the role of a business analyst in a datawarehouse application with example? 
Like a domain in credit card merchant data warehouse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This a very broad and subjective question.

In a nutshell, it depends heavily on to analyst level of involvement to date.

The best case scenario is when the analyst has already answered the clients questions and your job is only turn a pile of ad-hoc SQL queries into a DWH model (star scheme, conformed dimensions etc.) with daily updates and OLAP layer to facilitate reporting.

The worst case scenario is when the analyst is a total layman in this field and hence can offer little to no help at all.

For in between scenarios – have a look on this schematic breakdown of DWH project phases

- Understand **customer requirements** – an analyst can help bridge the gap between the customer and IT lingo and also help formulate useful KPIs\Measures
- Understand **available data** - an analyst can help locate source tables, understand relationships, JOIN and WHERE conditions etc
- **Design** solution – an analyst is a customer for this phase, i.e, a good DWH model should be understandable for data analysts in terms of entities, naming conventions etc.
- **Deliver** (including QA) - an analyst with good understanding of the business metrics (is 1M$ monthly sales real or is it a bug) can have a huge impact on this critical phase